# MVC DoddleReports 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have recently, as in about an hour ago, tried to implement the DoddleReports functionality into my MVC application.

Pretty positive I followed the documentation to the T. However, when I go to input my URL it gives me a 404 not found. I installed the packages via NuGet and I only need Excel so I added OpenXML (along with the dependencies).

My controller:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using VAGTC.Models;
using VAGTC.ViewModels;
using VAGTC.Helpers;
using DoddleReport.Web;
using DoddleReport;

namespace VAGTC.Controllers
{

    public class reportsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Excel/
        VAGTCEntities db = new VAGTCEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ReportResult OrganizationReport()
        {
            var matrix = from d in db.Organizations
                         select d;
            var report = new Report(matrix.ToReportSource());


            return new ReportResult(report);
        }
    }
}
```

The RouterConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using DoddleReport.Web;

    namespace VAGTC
    {
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapReportingRoute();
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When I installed Doddle with NuGet - it also automatically inputted the stuff needed in the web.config (not the web.config in the View folder!). I read a comment, [right here](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration), in the documentation for configuring Doddle with MVC and replaced the code. (but it also didn't work with code that was auto-generated). I didn't get fancy with customizing anything yet as I just wanted to get it working first!

So, how come the 404 page is coming up? It makes me seem it is something with routing but I am unsure of what specifically.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using it in debug mode - so maybe that could be a reason? This is the link I am using:

EDIT* Uploaded to my site and still gives a 404.

```
http://localhost:2530/reports/OrganizationReport.xls
```

EDIT 2* 
      After messing around, and changing a couple things according to the forum post given by @fiorebat. I debugged it right after it generates the report, `var report = new Report(matrix.ToReportSource());` and it gives this error once it returns the report.

```
No Source Available
There is no source code available for the current location.

Call stack location:
DoddleReport.dll!DoddleReport.ReportBuilder.ToReportSource(System.Collections.IEnumerable source) Line 12

Source file information:
Locating source for 'c:\Users\Matt\Development\Projects\DoddleReport\src\DoddleReport\ReportBuilder.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {61 dc e5 8e 25 79 c2 94 c4 27 5b d0 d7 92 56 ae}
The file 'c:\Users\Matt\Development\Projects\DoddleReport\src\DoddleReport\ReportBuilder.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Users\Matt\Development\Projects\DoddleReport\src\DoddleReport\ReportBuilder.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Users\Matt\Development\Projects\DoddleReport\src\DoddleReport\ReportBuilder.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\vccorlib\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...
Looking in directory 'C:\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Users\Matt\Development\Projects\DoddleReport\src\DoddleReport\ReportBuilder.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Users\Matt\Development\Projects\DoddleReport\src\DoddleReport\ReportBuilder.cs'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add under the system.webServer in the web config this configuration:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" ></modules>
```

I have same issue, report without extension works, i debug the route with "RouteDebuggin" and it's working. Seems that DoodleReport plugin don't calls the correct action.

http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/discussions/348486

Comment: Thank you - this helped a little. 
`var matrix = from d in db.Organizations
select d;`
When I change this code to `d.OrganizationID` the page loads but it is blank. When I just have it `select d;` the page sits at load time. I also removed and "ignoreroutes" line in my RouteConfig.

Comment: I have exactly copied over the product repository, and other associated items, from the sample DoddleReport. It still gives me a 404 error when I add an extension. Without an extension it simple loads a table into the browser.

Comment: I abbandoned doddle reports, developed this solution: http://www.manik-software.co.uk/blog/post/Export-to-Excel-xlsx-from-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

At start there's a lot of code, but after you can easily scaffold and reuse view actions

Comment: This is NO solution at all. Do you ever understand what that settings means? Enabling that will make EVERY SINGLE http request go through the ASP.NET pipeline, including css, text, javascript, images... it has a drastic negative impact on performances. I am very displeased to see that this is the only solution proposed so far. If there's no other way to make it work I'll be forced to drop doddle reports.

Comment: For a small traffic enterprise application like mine, is not a problem.
In other case, DoodleReports is abandoned, there's better solutions like http://www.manik-software.co.uk/blog/?year=2011&month=12
replacing openxml with closedxml plugin